# The expectation of a hermitian matrix quadratic form $E\left[ \mathbf{XF}{{\mathbf{F}}^{H}}{{\mathbf{X}}^{H}} \right]$

Tags: matrices, expected-value, quadratic-forms, hermite-polynomials

Suppose the random matrix $\mathbf{X}\in {{C}^{{{N}_{b}}\times {{N}_{a}}}}$, $\mathbf{X}=diag\left[ {{\mathbf{X}}_{1}},{{\mathbf{X}}_{2}},\cdots ,{{\mathbf{X}}_{R}} \right]$. The submatrix ${{\mathbf{X}}_{i}}\in {{C}^{{{N}_{b,i}}\times {{N}_{a,i}}}},i=1,2,\cdots ,R$ is assumed to have i.i.d. $CN \left( 0,\sigma _{i}^{2} \right)$ entries. ${{\mathbf{X}}_{i}}$ is independent of ${{\mathbf{X}}_{j}}$ for $i\ne j$. Thus, we have $E\left[ \mathbf{X}{{\mathbf{X}}^{H}} \right]={{\mathbf{\Omega }}_{X}}=diag\left( \sigma _{1}^{2}\mathbf{I},\sigma _{2}^{2}\mathbf{I},\cdots ,\sigma _{R}^{2}\mathbf{I} \right)$.

The matrix $\mathbf{F}\in {{C}^{{{N}_{a}}\times {{N}_{c}}}}$ is deterministic, and the entries in $\mathbf{F}$ could be real or complex. In general, ${{N}_{c}}<{{N}_{a}}<{{N}_{b}}$.

The matrices $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{F}$ are assumed to be independent of each other.

Assume $\mathbf{F}=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   \mathbf{F}_{1}^{r}  \\
   \mathbf{F}_{2}^{r}  \\
   \vdots   \\
   \mathbf{F}_{R}^{r}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$. Then 
\begin{align}
  & E\left[ \mathbf{XF}{{\mathbf{F}}^{H}}{{\mathbf{X}}^{H}} \right] \\ 
 & =E\left[ \begin{matrix}
   {{\mathbf{X}}_{1}}\mathbf{F}_{1}^{r}\mathbf{F}{{_{1}^{r}}^{H}}\mathbf{X}_{1}^{H} & \cdots  & \mathbf{0}  \\
   \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
   \mathbf{0} & \cdots  & {{\mathbf{X}}_{R}}\mathbf{F}_{R}^{r}\mathbf{F}{{_{R}^{r}}^{H}}\mathbf{X}_{R}^{H}  \\
\end{matrix} \right] \\ 
 & =\left[ \begin{matrix}
   E\left[ {{\mathbf{X}}_{1}}\mathbf{F}_{1}^{r}\mathbf{F}{{_{1}^{r}}^{H}}\mathbf{X}_{1}^{H} \right] & \cdots  & \mathbf{0}  \\
   \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
   \mathbf{0} & \cdots  & E\left[ {{\mathbf{X}}_{R}}\mathbf{F}_{R}^{r}\mathbf{F}{{_{R}^{r}}^{H}}\mathbf{X}_{R}^{H} \right]  \\
\end{matrix} \right]  
\end{align}

My question is:
Considering the feature of $\mathbf{X}_{i}$, how to further simplify $E\left[ {{\mathbf{X}}_{i}}\mathbf{F}_{i}^{r}\mathbf{F}{{_{i}^{r}}^{H}}\mathbf{X}_{i}^{H} \right]$?

Comment: The random matrix $XF\in C^{N_b\times N_b}$ is Gaussian, you can decompose it in blocks $(XF)_i\in C^{N_{b,i}\times N_b}$ that are independent. Hence $E[XAX^H]=\sum_i E[(XF)_i (XF)_i^T]$

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the dimension of the matrix $\mathbf{F}$ from $\mathbf{F}\in {{C}^{{{N}_{a}}\times {{N}_{b}}}}$ to $\mathbf{F}\in {{C}^{{{N}_{a}}\times {{N}_{c}}}}$, ${{N}_{c}}\ne {{N}_{b}}$.

Comment: Concerning your last question $E\left[ \mathbf{XFy}{{\mathbf{y}}^{H}}{{\mathbf{F}}^{H}}{{\mathbf{X}}^{H}} \right] = E\left[ E [\mathbf{XFy}{{\mathbf{y}}^{H}}{{\mathbf{F}}^{H}}{{\mathbf{X}}^{H}}|y] \right] = E\left[ \mathbf{XF}E[{{\mathbf{yy}}^{H}}|y]{{\mathbf{F}}^{H}}{{\mathbf{X}}^{H}} \right]=E\left[ \mathbf{XF}{{\mathbf{F}}^{H}}{{\mathbf{X}}^{H}} \right]$

Comment: Got your explanation. Thanks a lot.